# Ubuntu Studio 12.0.4 & Mozilla Firefox Input Text Glitch

Tags: firefox, themes, text

I am experiencing a serious issue with the **"Dark Theme"** functionality in Ubuntu Studio 12.0.4 (Low Latency) & Mozilla Firefox 17.0.1.  The Google Search Engine Field input text is rendering **"Light Grey"**. It is in fact so faint that it is nearly undetectable to the naked eye without highlighting the input text.

[image: Google Light Grey Search Field Entry]

Is there a way to force Mozilla Firefox to render standard colors?  How can I prevent the theme colors from rendering in the web browser?  There have been similar issues reported on previous versions of Mozilla Firefox. Please view this entry below:

[**https://askubuntu.com/questions/183564/high-contrast-theme-firefox-prob**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183564/high-contrast-theme-firefox-prob)

Here is a Screenshot of the Ubuntu Theme on my desktop before the assumption is made that my applied Firefox Theme is causing the **"Light Grey Text"** you see. You may view this below:

[image: Ubuntu Studio 12.0.4 (Low Latency) Desktop Theme]

The **"Light Grey Text Form Field Issue"** has been present way before I added my Mozilla Firefox 17.0.1 Theme.  Whensoever I choose the default "**Ubuntu 12.0.4"** Theme the **"Light Grey Text"** issue disappears as the input text becomes **Black**.  I've done a complete uninstall of Mozilla Firefox 17.0.1 in an attempt to remedy this issue utilizing the "**Synaptic Package Manager"**.  I was also sure to purge any remnant Mozilla Firefox files (customizations etc.). As an added step I've also been sure to review any Mozilla Firefox settings that may be causing this issue. This is just one more Screenshot so that you can see the "Use System Colors" check box under Firefox Preferences is unticked:

[image: Use System Colors Mozilla Firefox Preferences Unticked]

I've researched this all to no avail.  Please keep in mind that I am a Ubuntu novice that requires a detailed explanation as I am migrating from MAC OSX & Windows 7. I am diligently seeking a fix for this as I don't wish to change my theme just to have Mozilla Firefox function properly.

This issue has been reported to Bugzilla@Mozilla for further troubleshooting and observation and I have received a response. You may view that bug report here: [Bugzilla Bug Submission](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=824639) I will provide further updates in the comments section as warranted regarding Mozilla's response.

Comment: Well done with all the research and time you put into this, but bugs are off topic and so I've just voted to close it. Hope you get this resolved soon and in the meantime have a browse of the site FAQs linked at the top of the page.

Comment: Question to ask you does closing this mean that the information isn't there for anyone else to view?  There is a similar entry regarding this same issue. It would be nice if someone with a similar issue could be alerted to the fact that this is a bug as opposed to investing time and effort with resolution. Once the version of Mozilla Firefox changed the fix which was once applied is now no longer applicable.:(  See this entry: [link] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/183564/high-contrast-theme-firefox-problem) _italic_ **bold** 'code'

Comment: @UbuntuNovice Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You may want to file a downstream bug on Launchpad also (and link it to the upstream bug--which you recently filed--by using "Also Affects Project" on the Launchpad bug page). See the [downstream bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first of course. As for the question about closure, using Ask Ubuntu as a to report and investigate bugs fragments debugging and prevents bugs from actually getting fixed; see [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions) and [this meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/226/22949).

Comment: Closing a question does *not* remove it from view. (It does make it so no new answers can be posted.) However, except for questions that are closed because they are [duplicates](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/) of questions that are good for our site, closed questions without great answers are often *eventually* deleted (and then most users *cannot* see them). Please see the FAQ and feel free to post on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) to ask questions about the site itself (but please do not ask questions on meta that are not about Ask Ubuntu).

Comment: Pardon me however it is my understanding that 3rd party apps and questions related to them can be answered here. This started out as a question based on information in a prior post.  This is already closed and if there was a way to remove the prior question which was incorrect that slated a fix to this issue I would. Thank you very much.

Comment: ^Question about third party apps are ontopic here, but not bug reports:)

Comment: @UbuntuNovice I recommend posting a question on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) if you have questions about why this was closed or about what Tom Brossman, Tachyons, or I have said. Comments are not a great place to do this because they tend to form huge walls of text, because they are far more subject to removal and editing by moderators than other content on the site, and because if you ask on meta, then other people who are thinking the same as you can also participate. Also, please note that if you think a question was *wrongly closed*, meta is usually a good place to post about that.