# StackOverflow code segment font changed, possibly after changing System fonts

Tags: 12.10, themes, fonts

I am on Ubuntu 12.10 (using *firefox*, but the same font appears on chrome too) and I've been changing the theme and fonts of the system using ubuntu tweak tool.

The problem is that the code segments at the questions/replies now use the Monaco font while the code segment at the comments use the classic font used here (I think it's Ubuntu Mono).

Here is how it looks:
[image: code segment font]

How can I make all the code segments use the classic Ubuntu Mono font?

Comment: Can you edit your question and tell us if you are using Chrome or Firefox as your browser.

Comment: If you look through the answers to this question,http://askubuntu.com/questions/183564/high-contrast-theme-firefox-problem/183591#183591 you will find your answer. It appears that the stylesheet is looking for a font which can not display the <code>...</code> sections of the page. If this doesn't work, It may be worth asking on the Stack Exchange website what HTML tags are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this site-specific rule:

```
@-moz-document domain(stackoverflow.com)  
{ code { font-family: "Ubuntu Mono" !important; } }
```